# grepping/awking to remove entire line that contains a specific character

Tags: awk, grep

I have a grep (possibly awk?) question.
I have the following data (2 col, tab-separated).

```
a._testudineus  anm
a_battery   art
a_capella_singing   act|psy
a_cappella_singing  act|psy
```

I want to remove all LINES that contain the character "|"

For instance, my desired result would be the following:

```
a._testudineus  anm
a_battery   art
```

Is there a quick/efficient grep/awk that can help me with this?
The data is very large (approx 5GB).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`grep` is the tool:

```
$ grep -v "|" file
a._testudineus  anm
a_battery   art
```

You can also use `awk`, of course:

```
$ awk '!/\|/' file
a._testudineus  anm
a_battery   art
```

I would go for `grep`s way, as this tool is specifically created for things like this: `man grep` says `print lines matching a pattern`.

---

In fact, let's copy the file 1000 times and compare the time of execution:

```
$ wc file
  4404   8808 101292 file
```

Funny enough, the time is quite similar:

```
$ time grep -v "|" file
real    0m0.031s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.012s

$ time awk '!/\|/' file
real    0m0.030s
user    0m0.005s
sys     0m0.010s
```

And with 10000 lines also:

```
$ wc file
  44404   88808 1021292 file

$ time grep -v "|" file
real    0m0.300s
user    0m0.028s
sys     0m0.068s

$ time awk '!/\|/' file
real    0m0.314s
user    0m0.009s
sys     0m0.063s
```

Answer (score 0):

just add a sed line.

there are many text processing tools under linux/unix.  for lazy man(like me), knowing sed,awk,grep (maybe sort too), may handle 90%+ problems. :)

```
sed '/|/d' file
```